# how to break out of a void method, if not with "return;"

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

How do I break out of a void method and get back to the switch method?

```
    public static void decrypt() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner kbrd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Key-file name: ");
    String filename = kbrd.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Message-filename: ");
    String mssgFilename = kbrd.nextLine();
    String[] keyArray = loadMessage(filename);
    String[] message = loadMessage(mssgFilename);
    String[] cipher = xor2(message, keyArray);
    String readable = showText(cipher);
    System.out.println("The text:" + readable);
    return;
}
```

and then here is the switch method

```
    System.out.println("Encrypt  1.");
    System.out.println("Decrypt  2.");
    System.out.println("Make Key 3.");
    System.out.println("Quit     4.");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = scan.nextLine();

    do {
        switch (choice) {
        case "1":
            encrypt();
            break;
        case "2":
            decrypt();
            break;
        case "3":
            makeKey();
            break;

        }

    } while (choice != "4");
```

Problem is, whatever I choose it stays in that method despite the return statement at the end , shouldn't that bring me back to the switch method?

Comment: Your code is doing what you are asking - whats the problem?  Is some method blocking?

Comment: You don't actually need the `return;`, once the `decrypt` exist, it will return to the point it was called.  Also, you might want to put your menu and `choice` input into the `do-while` loop

Comment: How does it stay? Can you be more descriptive on what really happens?

Comment: Please specify the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes, let's say I pick 'decript' I want it to execute that once then return to the switch statements for another choice, but it stays in decript after it has gone through it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the ability to add another choice into the loop.  You're currently entering into an infinite loop because `choice` does not change.

```
String choice;
do {
    choice = scanner.nextLine();
    switch (choice) {
        case "1":
            encrypt();
            break;
        case "2":
            decrypt();
            break;
        case "3":
            makeKey();
            break;
    } 
} while (!choice.equals("4"));
```

Observe that this has nothing to do with the methods being called; this is entirely regulated by the do...while loop.

Comment: You missed this one: `while (!choice.equals("4"));`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a loop that goes in infinite loop as the choice is read only once. You enter 3 once and it goes into a loop with the condition `choice != '4'`, and it is always true, as you dont change your choice. So your function is called over and over again. (It **does break out** of the function but it is called over and over again) Put the input lines inside the loop.